# Aptana Studio 3 - Can't find .bashrc when I go to terminal

Tags: aptana

Just installed Aptana Studio 3 build 3.0.4.201108101506 on Mac OS X Snow Leopard.  I created a new rails project from existing source.  When I open a terminal or choose "Run Server" or "Rails console", it opens a terminal in the directory of the application (expected), but gives the message:

bash: .bashrc: No such file or directory

If I source the .bashrc that is in my home directory, then everything begins to work fine.

How can I instruct Aptana to do this for me automatically?  I've searched and can't seem to find anyone with a similar problem, so maybe there is a configuration issue.

Comment: Do you have git installed, as is required for using Aptana? It uses this bash shell to execute commands.

Comment: You should also make sure that your login PATH is set up correctly such that you can execute the ruby, gem, rails, and git commands correctly. Setting these things up in your .bashrc (or equivalent) isn't sufficient, because it doesn't get evaluated by default when GUI applications like Aptana Studio 3 get launched.

Comment: Yes, git is installed, and I have cloned a project.  I'm able to execute ruby, gem, rails, and git after opening that terminal where I see the error.

However, if I type rails server, or rails console, those both fail until I have sourced my .bashrc, which contains the line:
[[ -s "/Users/zwickilton/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "/Users/zwickilton/.rvm/scripts/rvm"

Answer (score 0):

Looks like we're not sourcing .bashrc, which according to bash manual seems correct: http://stefaanlippens.net/bashrc_and_others

As a workaround you can create a ~/.aptanarc file that sources .bashrc. But ideally you'd move the RVM lines into your .bash_profile since that's something we do source and is the preferred location for it according to RVM docs: http://beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/

For reference, here's what we currently run when we start the shell on Mac:

```
unset BASH_ENV

if [ -f /etc/profile ] ; then . /etc/profile; fi

if [ -f ~/.bash_profile ] ; then . ~/.bash_profile;
elif [ -f ~/.bash_login ] ; then . ~/.bash_login;
elif [ -f ~/.profile ] ; then . ~/.profile;
fi

if [[ $LANG == "" ]] ; then
  export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
fi

if [[ "$HOME" != `pwd` ]] ; then
  [[ -f .rvmrc && -n $rvm_version ]] && source .rvmrc
fi

[[ -f ~/.aptanarc ]] && . ~/.aptanarc
```